# Como solicitar a avaliação no aplicativo android?

Tags: java, android

Queria por a opção da pessoa avaliar o app depois de 2 vezes por exemplo que entrar nele, e já levar para play store, alguém sabe?

Comment: cara eu não entendi muito bem.. tem outro exemplo?

Comment: A única maneira de solicitar a avaliação é abrir um `Dialog`, perguntando se ele deseja avaliar ou não, se ele quiser, abre uma `Intent` que vai enviar o usuário para a página do teu aplicativo na loja. Não existe uma maneira de avaliar no aplicativo.